# Amending the results order of a hierarchical query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table defining a hierarchy of ZONES as shown here:

[image]:

Along with it, I'm using the following query:

```
WITH My_CTE(Zone, Parent, LEVEL , treepath) AS
    ( SELECT Zone_ID                            AS Zone   , 
             Parent_ID                          AS Parent , 
             0                                  AS LEVEL  ,
             ISNULL(CAST(Parent_ID  AS VARCHAR(1024)),'')  AS treepath
        FROM [UWQ].[T_SYS_Zones]
       WHERE Parent_ID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.Zone_ID                            AS Zone   , 
           d.Parent_ID                          AS Parent ,
           My_CTE.LEVEL + 1                     AS LEVEL    ,
           CAST(My_CTE.treepath + ' > ' + CAST(d.Parent_ID AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS treepath
           FROM [UWQ].[T_SYS_Zones] d

    INNER JOIN My_CTE
        ON My_CTE.Zone = d.Parent_ID
    )

SELECT *
  FROM My_CTE
 ORDER BY level , treepath;
```

This query does return the needed information except that I need it in a different order, meaning, each Zone is recursively listed with its children and children's children till exhaustion and only then the next **brother** is listed.

Using the data shown in the table, the result should be something like this:

```
Zone    Parent    LEVEL    treepath
0        NULL    0    
1        0        1         > 0
2        1        2         > 0 > 1
8        2        3         > 0 > 1 > 2
9        2        3         > 0 > 1 > 2
10       2        3         > 0 > 1 > 2
12       2        3         > 0 > 1 > 2
29       10       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 10
30       10       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 10
31       10       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 10
32       10       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 10
33       10       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 10
34       10       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 10
11       2        3         > 0 > 1 > 2
35       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
36       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
37       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
38       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
39       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
40       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
41       11       4         > 0 > 1 > 2 > 11
3        1        2         > 0 > 1
...
```

I tried playing with the shape of the treepath field with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding an actual sequence, similar to your tree path, you can easily get the proper order/nesting.  See the derived field `SEQ`

The @Top is optional, it allows you generate the tree from any node.  NULL will be the full hierarchy.

You may notice the `100000+Row_Number()` This is to ensure proper sequencing and avoids mis-orders like 1,10,11

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Zone_ID int,Parent_ID int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
(0, NULL),(1, 0),(2, 1),(8, 2),(9, 2),(10,2),(12,2),(29,10),(30,10),(31,10),(32,10),(33,10),(34,10),(11,2),(35,11),(36,11),(37,11),(38,11),(39,11),(40,11),(41,11),(3, 1)      

Declare @Top  int = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 3 

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(100000+Row_Number() over (Order by Zone_ID) as varchar(500))
            ,Zone_ID
            ,Parent_ID
            ,Level=1
            ,treepath = ISNULL(CAST(Parent_ID AS VARCHAR(1024)),'') 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(Parent_ID,-1) else Zone_ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',100000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Zone_ID)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.Zone_ID
            ,r.Parent_ID
            ,p.Level+1
            ,CAST(p.treepath + ' > ' + CAST(r.Parent_ID AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS VARCHAR(1024))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent_ID = p.Zone_ID)
Select Zone_ID
      ,Parent_ID
      ,Level
      ,treepath
 From cteP 
 Order By Seq
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: @FDavidov Happy it helped